# Prism.js not working properly in some cases React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prismjs

I have a react & typescript application. It's a blog post and I'm fetching markdown from an API. I'm parsing it using [showdown](http://showdownjs.com/).

The problem is that the syntax highlighting is not working on the fetched code but some of my own code is working fine:

```js
export default function BlogDetail() {

    const mdContainerRef = useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            if (mdContainerRef.current) {
                const parser = new Converter();
                const html = parser.makeHtml(data.body_markdown);

                Prism.highlightAll();

                mdContainerRef.current.innerHTML = html
                    .replaceAll('<h3', '<h3 class="text-4xl mt-7 mb-2"')
                    .replaceAll('<h5', '<h5 class="text-xl mt-5"');
                // .replaceAll(
                //  '<pre><code class="js language-js"',
                //  '<pre class="javascript language-javascript"><code class="javascript language-javascript"'
                // ).replaceAll('<pre><code class="css language-css"', '<pre class="css // language-css"><code class="css language-css"');
            }

            setArticle(data);
        })();
    }, [slug, mdContainerRef]);

    return (
            <pre>
                <code className='language-javascript'>
                    {`onSubmit(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        const job = {
                            title: 'Developer',
                            company: 'Facebook' 
                        };
                    }`}
                </code>
            </pre>

            <div ref={mdContainerRef}></div>
    );
}
```

The `pre` & `code` elements which I'm rendering have perfect syntax highlighting(I've imported prism.css too). However, the fetched markup is not showing any signs of syntax highlighting. Here's a pic of the elements in the console[image]

As you can see, there is some formatting, for example, the font is changed and so is the color of the text.

Now, here's a pic of some css code:

[image]

As you can see, both of them don't have syntax highlighting. However, let me draw your attention to the the `pre` and `code` elements:

[image]

Ignore the indentation, but the highlighting seems to be working fine.

If you have noticed, there's some commented code above. When I uncomment that, it looks like this:

[image]

The background has changed but there's still no syntax highlighting.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm open to use other highlighting options, please provide a demo/sample code or give a link to the docs

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, fetching markdown and then this happened. Any solutions you got ??

Comment: Unfortunately not :(